# How to know when an .xlsx file has been updated?

Tags: json, excel, csv, xlsx

I want to export data from an excel file, but I want to know how can I listen to that event, the event of saving a file, and then, export that data into .csv and convert it to JSON and then storing that info into a web server database.

Another approach I have is set up a cron every x minutes.

Can I do this with python or I need some excel API or something like that?

Comment: How do you want to listen to the Save event?  If you're running VBA inside the Excel workbook, you can catch the `BeforeSave` or `AfterSave` events. If you're monitoring the Excel file from outside of the workbook (e.g. a python or powershell script), then periodically checking the file's timestamp will let you know when to re-export the new data.

Comment: Another option is to connect the spreadsheet to you web server as a data connection, your server/database/api needs to support this of course, but then Excel will show update and refresh buttons to the user.